# How to fix Bubble Size in Bubble Chart created using Python-Pptx

Tags: bubble-chart, python-pptx

I created bubble chart in powerpoint using python-pptx but not able to control bubble size. Would highly appreciate if someone can guide me.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please review [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order for others to be able to help you. A good place to start would be to add examples of what you have tried already.

Comment: [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)